# What type of famous equation except diophantine equation such that no algorithm can exist to determine whether there is a solution?

Tags: abstract-algebra, math-history

What type of famous equation except diophantine equation such that no algorithm can exist to determine whether there is a solution?

I know that if these equation have a solution, then it could be solving with finite amount of time.

By the way, how long does mathematician tend to give up for solving such equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The impossibility of solving diophantine equations in general leads to a number of other impossibility results.  For example, Richardson's theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%27s_theorem says that in a certain class of functions there is no
algorithm to test whether the function is identically $0$.